# WinForms txtTextbox_MouseEnter firing for all textboxes on form

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, event-handling, mouseenter

I have a form with five textboxes. On a button click event I check if any of the textboxes are empty and if so, the empty textboxes have the background color set to LightPink.

I want to set the background color back to the default when the user enters the textbox to enter a value. I tried `txtTextbox_MouseEnter` to do that but the event is firing when other textboxes get focus with a mouse click. Oddly, the txtTextBox_MouseEnter event doesn't always fire when any textbox is clicked on - just sometimes - can't seem to determine a pattern in that behavior.

Why is this happening and what's the correct way to accomplish my goal?

Comment: You probably want handle the `txtTextbox.Enter` event. Do you have the same handler for all your TextBoxes? If so, cast `sender` to `Control` (or `TextBox` or `TextBoxBase`) and set its `BackColor` property.

Comment: @Jimi, that did the trick, thanks. But why was the MouseEnter event firing for that textbox when other textboxes were being clicked on?

Comment: Because you're using the same handler for more than one control? I can't see your code, so...